# How to use Zend Framework's “BjyAuthorize” to obtain an array of logged user roles

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is this a method to obtain array of logged user roles? When I request:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ProviderInterface')->getIdentityRoles()
```

I receive array of big doctrine objects. I like to receive an array like in ZendDeveloperTools toolbar.

I'm using with this doctrine:

```
'bjyauthorize' => array(
    // Using the authentication identity provider, which basically reads the roles from the auth service's identity
    'identity_provider' => 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\AuthenticationIdentityProvider',
    'role_providers' => array(
        // using an object repository (entity repository) to load all roles into our ACL
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ObjectRepositoryProvider' => array(
            'object_manager' => 'doctrine.entity_manager.orm_default',
            'role_entity_class' => 'Application\Entity\Role',
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The role entities should implement Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\RoleInterface. This interface consists of a single method, getRoleId(), so you can foreach on the collection to build an array of RoleIds.

Comment: i know this, but what i asked if there is already a method for direct array reponse or i must to extend something because is not nice that foreach everytime i need to check if have a role or not